# CSS what wrong with padding / margin / border

Tags: html, css

UPDATED: Done with top padding, but my left column still didnt fit into background? Need some containers?

left column code :

```
    #leftcolumn {
     background: url('SlicingImage/action_bar.jpg');
     background-repeat:repeat-y;
     float:left;
     height:100%;
    }
```

This my expected result (left column) [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ8NK.jpg)

This my result [now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Rw9b.png)

My leftColumn didnt auto fit into the background :(

Comment: Your question is vague, there can be numerous possibilities for that breakage...

Comment: @Mr.Alien thats why I ask what wrong :) because I didnt know how to fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the margin and padding in your css.

```
body {
   ....
   margin:0; 
   padding:0;

   //update
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}
```

Comment: ? I don't think that's the issue

Comment: how to reset? I tried inserting this code to body {} but still no response?

Comment: I think we need some more code, because you could have a floating problem as wel..

Comment: Check the update.., cant you make a JsFiddle? with your code?

Comment: still the top have some space :( and my left column didnt expand until bottom of the page?

Comment: Thats because you have to use `height:100%` on `#leftcolumn`

Comment: What is jsfiddle? Like I said, this is my 1st try to make css :(  ( never learn about js or jquery either)

Comment: Ohh sorry, JsFiddle is a website were you can put you code.. to see how it works. and a lot of people use it to explain there problem and to show it. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Oh okay, I'll do that tomorrow, thanks for following this question :)

Comment: @CTravel I tried the jsfiddle but seems like I cant, because I'm using own pic for the css.. but the padding problem fixed, only the left column auto height problem :) if you can help me again

Comment: I will be online today for 8 hours, so when you read this, we can go to the chat, so i can help you.